# Degree of Obfuscation

Tags: windows, phone, obfuscation

Let us assume that I have the following code:

```
namespace MobileApp
{
    public class Storage
    {
        public Storage()
        {

        }

        public bool Save()
        {
            bool success = false;

            try
            {
                var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

                if (settings.Contains("AppInformation7563"))
                {
                    settings["AppInformation7563"] = "GG3MDhlxnZDdDx7";
                }
                else
                {
                    settings.Add("AppInformation7563", "GG3MDhlxnZDdDx7");
                }

                settings.Save();
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                success = false;
            }
            return success;
        }

        public string Load()
        {
            string app = "false";

            try
            {
                var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

                if (settings.Contains("AppInformation7563"))
                {
                    app = settings["AppInformation7563"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                app = "false";
            }
            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, this code stores a secret password in Windows Phone isolated storage so that this password is passed whenever a web service call is made.

If I obfuscate the code using DotFuscator, will the "AppInformation7653" and "GG3MDhlxnZDdDx7" be obfuscated as well?  Or will they remain the same, just the names of the classes and variables are changed?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Why would an attacker care? They can simply read the value from isolated storage.

Comment: How can they read it from isolated storage?  As far as I know, only the application can access that part of memory.  Am I right?

Comment: My assumption is that the attacker can root the phone after which they can access whatever they want.

Comment: Hmm...  So how can I store the key securely please?  Thank you.

Comment: First of all, how can the attacker root the phone?  Does he require physical access to the phone?

Comment: If you want to keep something secret from the owner of the device you're usually out of luck. What is the goal of the encryption? DRM schemes are pretty much the only reason for hiding keys, but they're broken-by-design.

Comment: Well, my application communicates with a web service.  I decided to store a secret code inside the application which is passed to the web service call in order to ensure that the call is being made from the mobile app and not from a desktop app for example.

Comment: Obfuscation has merit in some cases, but I can't see it here. Assuming that you use SSL for the connection to the service and that the API is not published, you are secure by default from a desktop app until someone discovers the protocol through reverse engineering. If a reverse engineer has discovered the protocol, they will likely have observed the key in use too, and obfuscation has got you nothing. I suggest a rethink of why and how you are going about this.

Comment: Your "secrret code" can be part of a two part key, the other part of which the server provides at run-time, and the two are used together to hash something. I forget what this is called... Digest Authentication? The key alone is of no value. Someone could still copy it out though. The point about protecting something that is in someone's possession is valid. I guess you could use Qbits or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DotFuscator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator) will "encrypt" string literals, although I cringe at the use of the word "encryption" in that context. Your string values "AppInformation7653" and "GG3MDhlxnZDdDx7" won't appear "as is" in the resulting assembly, but the code necessarily contains everything that is needed to rebuild their respective values at runtime. So don't believe that such obfuscation will actually thwart [reverse engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering); it may just deter the least motivated or competent of attackers, but skilled attackers will just laugh at your feeble attempts at obfuscation.

As usual, code obfuscation is more about giving a *feeling* of security than actually making things more secure. The real value of obfuscation is that it demonstrate your *intent* of keeping the code internals somewhat secret, which can be handy in some legal situations (a reverse-engineer will not be able to claim that he "didn't know", in good faith, that the code was not supposed to be scrutinized that way). As will all things legal, this may or may not work in any specific jurisdiction, and I am not competent to give any specific legal advice anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :)  I appreciate the time you took in order to answer my question in this high level of detail :)  Thank you so much :)  And sorry for responding 5 days late :s

Answer (score 2):

Your public class and method names **won't** change, because they're externally referenceable, they can't.  Since public types may be used by other libraries and applications that the obfuscator has no knowledge off, they must be preserved.

As to the string values, they may or may not be obfuscated.  They usually are, but I haven't used DotFuscator, so I don't know specifically how it works.   You should create an obfuscated build and then inspect it using a tool like Reflector or ILSpy to determine exactly what it's been able to do to your assembly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Xander :)  I appreciate it immensely :)  And sorry for responding 5 days late :s